# ¿Cómo incrementar una condición sobre el horario para segmentar en función de la hora?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Utilizo PostgreSQL. Quiero hacer una consulta SQL que me dice cuentos tiempos `state` es igual con `...`  según la hora. Es por decir hacer :

```
SELECT COUNT(*), date_trunc('hour', date) as datet
FROM swipe
WHERE swipe.state=2 OR swipe.state=3 OR swipe.state=5 OR swipe.state = 6 OR swipe.state=8 OR swipe.state = 9
GROUP BY 2
```

Pero para cada hora y cada día. Lo anterior me da :

```
count datet
6     2017-04-22 16:00:00.000000
2     2017-05-02 01:00:00.000000
4     2017-05-02 09:00:00.000000
2     2017-05-15 12:00:00.000000
5     2017-04-14 18:00:00.000000
5     2017-04-23 16:00:00.000000
```

Pero quiero la suma sobre las horas cualquier sea el día :

```
36    00:00:00.000000
22    01:00:00.000000
54    02:00:00.000000
332   03:00:00.000000
25    04:00:00.000000
5     05:00:00.000000
...
```

Lo mejor seria dar una fecha inicial y una fecha final.

Intenté hacerlo con la consulta:

```
WITH horas AS (
  SELECT generate_series (
  date_trunc('hour', '2017-1-1 00:00:00'::timestamp), -- fecha inicial
  '2017-2-1 00:00:00',                                -- fecha final
  '1 hour'::interval) AS hora
)
SELECT hora,
 ( SELECT count(*)
   FROM swipe
   WHERE  date_trunc('hour', date) = hora
     AND swipe.state=2 OR swipe.state=3 OR swipe.state=5 OR swipe.state = 6 OR swipe.state=8 OR swipe.state = 9
 ) --cantidad estados
FROM horas;
```

Pero me da un outupt un poquito extraño con cada hora el mismo numero de count:

```
2017-01-01 00:00:00.000000  396
2017-01-01 01:00:00.000000  396
2017-01-01 02:00:00.000000  396
2017-01-01 03:00:00.000000  396
2017-01-01 04:00:00.000000  396
2017-01-01 05:00:00.000000  396
2017-01-01 06:00:00.000000  396
```

Comment: Formula mejor tu pregunta por favor, el texto _cuntos tiempos hay una cosa_ es muy confuso

Comment: Quieres saber cuantos states se encuentran en una hora determinada?, quieres contar los state agrupados por fecha?

Comment: que tal si nos coloca un ejemplo de como se ven los datos y luego como quieres que se vean

Comment: @JackNavaRow Si esta es una buena idea, os coloco un ejemplo de como se ven los datos y luego como quiero que se vean

Comment: ( SELECT count(*)
   FROM swipe
   WHERE  date_trunc('hour', date) = hora
     AND swipe.state=2 OR swipe.state=3 OR swipe.state=5 OR swipe.state = 6 OR swipe.state=8 OR swipe.state = 9 group by swipe.state
 ) agrege el group by la consulta es igual para todas

Answer (score 0):

Tu pregunta está mal formulada. Pero si hago el esfuerzo de adivinar lo que quieres, supongo que algó así funcionará:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), state, date_trunc('hour', date) as datet 
FROM swipe
WHERE ...
GROUP BY 2 , 3
ORDER BY 3, 2 ;
```

Esto es que no mostrará nada para las horas vacías. 
Si quieres un listado con todas las horas, entonces:

```
 WITH horas AS ( 
  SELECT generate_series (
  date_trunc('hour', '2017-1-1 00:00:00'::timestamp), -- fecha inicial
  '2017-2-1 00:00:00',                                -- fecha final 
  '1 hour'::interval) AS hora
) 
SELECT hora, 
 ( SELECT count(*) 
   FROM swipe 
   WHERE  date_trunc('hour', date) = hora
     AND state = ...
 ) cantidad estados
FROM horas;
```

*Actualizado:*
El problema con tu nueva consulta es que el AND y el OR están mal combinandos. Es un error frecuente, conviene entenderlo. Si en SQL escribes 
`... WHERE X AND Y OR Z` esto se interpreta como `... WHERE (X AND Y) OR Z`  y no es lo que quieres. Cambialo a

```
 ... WHERE  date_trunc('hour', date) = hora  AND 
 ( swipe.state=2 OR swipe.state=3 OR swipe.state = 5 ... )
```

Aparte, ese OR queda más elegante así:

```
 ... WHERE  date_trunc('hour', date) = hora  AND 
 swipe.state IN (2,3,5...)
```

---

Actualizado: Lo que pides ahora (agreupando sobre horas, sin importar el dia) es bastante diferente - aunque deberías poder hacerlo por tu cuenta con lo anterior. (Y es bueno que lo intentes). Pero bueno, prueba con algo como

```
  WITH horas AS ( 
      SELECT generate_series (0,23) AS hora
    ) 
    SELECT hora, 
     ( SELECT count(*) 
       FROM swipe 
       WHERE  date_part('hour', date) = hora
         AND (state = ... )
     ) cantidad estados
    FROM horas;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, he actualizado la pregunta y lo escribes me sirve mucho. SIn embargo me hubiera gustado la suma sobre cada hora !

Comment: Mi consulta tira la suma (cuenta) sobre cada hora. Tu consulta tiene un bug, ahí lo explico.

Comment: Muchas gracias pero como hacer para haber un output sobre cada hora sumando por cada dias ? Esta para obtener por la uno de la mañana output = ..., por las doce output = ... ... es por decir hacer la suma sobre los días en función de la hora.